# access 'this' within http error callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I have the following controller and http request.

I'm setting connectionError to false and want to set it to true on the callbackError in the http request.

I get the following error when using `this`

`Cannot set property 'connectionError' of undefined`

Everything works fine when I use `$scope`.

I've read the following article https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/ which explains a lot about `this` and `scope` and kind of understand that in my code below the `this` that initially sets 'connectionError' to false is not the same `this` within the callbackError function as `this` refers to the function it resides in...?!? (well that's currently what I'm interpreting...)

So my question is - is there a way to set the 'connectionError' to true. Or is this a classic example where `$scope` is better suited?

Code:

```
var userApp = angular.module('UserApp', []);


userApp.controller('UserListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){

    var type = this;
    type.users = [];

    // doesn't work
    this.connectionError = false;
    // works
    $scope.connectionError = false;

    // get the data
    $http.get('./types/users.json')
        // on success
        .then(function successCallback(response){
            type.users = response.data;

        },
        // on error
        function errorCallback(response){
            // doesn't work
            this.connectionError = true;
            // works
            $scope.connectionError = true;
        });

}]);
```

Comment: inside controller or link function you have to use `$scope` for angular engine.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because this has a different value when used inside another function.

To use `this` of the controller function inside the error callback assign `this` to another variable in the controller. In this case you already did it with `type` variable so use it!

```
        function errorCallback(response){
            type.connectionError = true;
        });
```

And regarding `$scope`, especially if you are using controllerAs syntax, strongly avoid it.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I didn't see that, and I'm already using it in the callbackSuccess function.... :0 Too many hours staring at code.....!

Comment: I know i know man :) `this` usage in javascript is one of the most confusing things i stumbled upon, so i suggest you to open the console and make some experiment with it until you understand properly how it works. Also, take a look at ES6 fat arrow functions, which solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The context `this` in the error handler is not the one from main controller function. In strict mode, the context of a function invocation is `undefined`.
To solve this and have access to controller's `this`, use the `bind()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
$http.get('./types/users.json')
    // on success
    .then(function successCallback(response){
        type.users = response.data;

    },
    // on error
    function errorCallback(response){
        // Now will work
        this.connectionError = true;
        // works
        $scope.connectionError = true;
    }.bind(this));
```

See more details in [Gentle explanation of `this`](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/).

Comment: Thanks. Nice use of the bind method +1 and I learnt something new :D

Comment: @fidev You're welcome.